# Slow writes to Excel cell using Excel Interop in Winforms application

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, interop, winforms-interop

I'm looking some help with my code for writing data to an Excel worksheet.
I'm currently writing data to a single cell at a time which is taking around three seconds per cell. As you can imagine, this time really starts to add up when you start to get into hundreds of cells.

I'm aware that there is a method of saving to a range of cells but not entirely sure how to do this.

The document I am writing to is a questionnaire style spread sheet with columns: Number, Question, Yes, No, NA.
I loop through a list of user controls which hold the users selected answer from my form and then write it to the cell.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
if (QuestionList.Count > 0)
{
                    //loop round rows
                    for (int i = 0; i < QuestionList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //check that index is not null
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(QuestionList[i].Index))
                        {
                            //if the char in index is a letter
                            if (Char.IsLetter(QuestionList[i].Index[0]))
                            {
                                worksheet2.Cells[i + 1, 4].Value2 = QuestionList[i].Yes;
                                worksheet2.Cells[i + 1, 5].Value2 = QuestionList[i].No;
                                worksheet2.Cells[i + 1, 6].Value2 = QuestionList[i].NA;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: For your sake use Open XML SDK for excel generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to read multiple cell values in one go is to create a new Excel range, specifying the range of cells that you want to read.
You can then take the values within the range and put them into a multidimensional object array.
Then simply refer back to the cell position within the array to get values.

This will do one single read to get multiple cell values rather than a single read for each cell.

```
    string name;
    string dob;
    string address; 

    //excel range
    Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet1.Range["A1", "I10"];
    //range array
    object[,] rangeValueArray = range.Value2;
    
    //cell 1A
    if (rangeValueArray[1,1] != null)
    {
             name = rangeValueArray[1, 1].ToString();
    }
    
    //cell 1B
    if (rangeValueArray[1, 2] != null)
    {
             dob = rangeValueArray[1, 2].ToString();
    }
    
    //cell 1C
    if (rangeValueArray[1, 3] != null)
    {
             address = rangeValueArray[1, 3].ToString();
    }
```